# 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax. В чем ошибка в запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

{"xdebug_message":"\nZend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`56579.40`,`147934`.`6`.`10`.`64529.64`,`23482179`.`6`.`0`.`3476.85`,`147939`.`' at line 1, query was: REPLACE INTO` card_entity `(`23482173`.`6`.`10`.`56579.40`,`147934`.`6`.`10`.`64529.64`,`23482179`.`6`.`0`.`3476.85`,`147939`.`6`.`10`.`72235.89`,`23482181`.`6`.`4`.`16935.29`,`23482185`.`6`.`0`.`3675.97`) VALUES (?), (?), (?) in /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 110
...

Comment: replace into card_entity **VALUES** (...)? Что за набор цифр у вас идёт после названия таблицы? Это новые значения? Что тогда идёт параметризированное после values?

Comment: Весь запрос выглядит так: REPLACE INTO `card_entity` (`23482173`.`6`.`10`.`56579.40`,`147934`.`6`.`10`.`64529.64`,`23482179`.`6`.`0`.`3476.85`,`147939`.`6`.`10`.`72235.89`,`23482181`.`6`.`4`.`16935.29`,`23482185`.`6`.`0`.`3675.97`) VALUES (`discount_type`), (`discount_amount`), (`order_total_amount`);

Comment: И что он должен делать?

Comment: Что это за группы "цифры с точками"?

Comment: Этот запрос должен обновлять записи с id-шниками "23482173", "147934" и т.д. значениями через точки в колонках, что в скобках. Но он как-то непонятно построен, нужно разбираться...

Comment: Имена колонок обрамляются апострофами и выглядит это вот так `\`23482173.6.10.56579.40\``, а не как у вас